# How can i disable session for one action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have Rails 2.3.2 and I want to disable session support for one controller action, so that means that I don't want to save session variables to database when I'm accessing url. For example '/my_action' url.
I have tried to implement this using session :off, :only => :my_action but this doesn't work.

The message I recieve is:
DEPRECATION WARNING: Disabling sessions for a single controller has been deprecated. Sessions are now lazy loaded. So if you don't access them, consider them off. You can still modify the session cookie options with request.session_options..

Answer (score 0):

Session stores are lazy loaded since rails 2.3, rails loads session data only when you refer to session during the request life.

If you want to disable the session, then don't refer to session during request life time for given action.

[please have a look at rails 2.3 release notes for more information](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html)